# need an example about absolutely continuous measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

according to the Randon-Nikodym Thm when μ>>v there exist a non-negative function s.t v(E)= integral_E fdμ

so I was wondering if there exists a non-negative integrable function s.t

v(E)= integral_E fdμ 
but μ does not absolutely continuous w.r.t v

i start from if μ not >> v then v(E)=integral_E fdμ =1 when μ(E)=0 but i cant give out this function.
need help asap

Comment: more specifically i want " is not absolutely continuous with respect to ," but ()=∫ is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

When $\nu(E) = \int_E f \, d\mu$, then $\nu \ll \mu$ immediately since $\mu(E)=0$ implies $\nu(E) = \int_E f \, d\mu = 0$.
The Radon-Nikodym theorem states that the converse is also true.

By the way, $\nu \ll \mu$ is read as "$\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$," not the other way around.

Comment: I understand the Randon-Nikodym THM but I was asking if there exist an integrable function st ()=0 but ()=∫ not equal to 0 or ()=∫=0  but () not equal to 0

Comment: or more specifically i want " is not absolutely continuous with respect to ," but ()=∫ is that possible?

Comment: @Harry He understood the question! In fact he answered it - read wgatt he wrote...

Comment: @Harry My first sentence states that what you are asking for is impossible.